# Replacing the flash chip on a Galaxy Nexus

Tags: internal-storage, storage, sim-card, internal-sd

**A little background**

---

I have two Galaxy Nexus phones: one reported lost(was lost) 32GB and a current 16GB version.

**Current Issue**

---

I'm trying to put the 32GB flash chip into the current phone. Which means moving the SIM tray/flash card from the old phone to the new one. Shouldn't be too hard, just replace the circuit board and use the correct SIM card.

When I turn the phone on however, it says there is 0-1 bars of unusable signal(no data). I use the old tray and it works perfectly. Is there some chip in this board I don't know about?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this relates to the internal storage of the device. It sounds like you're just trying to swap the SIM. Moving the storage from one phone to the other would require opening them both up, desoldering the storage chips, and then resoldering one into the other (which it doesn't sound like you're doing). Also, if it works with the old tray, why not use that? Why do you need to swap the SIM trays *and* the SIM cards?

Comment: The SIM tray and internal flash chip are both on a removable circuit board. So to swap them I simply take it out of one and put it in the other(no soldering), keeping the working SIM card.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what parts you're referring to here. Maybe pictures would help or something. Are you trying to move the *entire* motherboard from one to the other? I'm not sure I even see the point in that, but then, I'm also not sure if that's what you're actually attempting to do.

Comment: I am with eldareathis. The flash memory is soldered to the main board. Short of desoldering/soldering there wouldn't be a way to simply swap something from one device to the other. And if you swap the whole board, the bad IMEI that was reported lost comes with it. Just use the 16gb one as a phone and the 32gb as a media player or something.

Comment: The memory is soldered to the main board of a non-Verizon phone. On Verizon phones, the memory is soldered to an add-on board that isn't even held in by screws...